# I'm getting "error: eslint terminated with error. [object Object] using Brackets IDE

Tags: javascript, eslint, adobe-brackets

I've downlaoded the Brackets IDE and I'm trying ti out. I loaded a .js file and cleaned it up but I'm getting an error message from ESLint:

> ESLint terminated with error. [object Object]

Here's the JavaScript code in qustion

```
/*jslint browser: false */
/*eslint browser: true */
/*
CLCP v2.1 Clear Links to Current Page
Jonathan Snook
This code is offered unto the public domain
http://www.snook.ca/jonathan/
*/

/* Modified, June 24, 2011 to add capability to change all or only the first link found,
by Bob Novell http://www.bobnovell.com
*/

function clearCurrentLink(changeAll) {
     "use strict";
     var a, i;
     a = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
     for (i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1) {
          if (a[i].href === window.location.href.split("#")[0]) {     // code ignores references to named anchors on the same page
               a[i].innerHTML = "<span class='currentlpage'>" + a[i].innerHTML + "</span>";
               removeNode(a[i]);
               if (changeAll === undefined) {  // if nothing is passed for changeAll, we only do one reset - in the navagation list - this is in case pages contain
                    return;                    // If you are unsure what to code for changeAll, specify true if you want all links changed and don't code anything
               }                              // if you want only the first link found changed - like if you only want to change the link in a navigation table.
          }
     }
}

function removeNode(n) {
     "use strict";
     var i;
     if (n.hasChildNodes()) {
          for (i = 0; i < n.childNodes.length; i = i + 1) {
               n.parentNode.insertBefore(n.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true), n);
          }
     }
     n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
}
```

Does anyone know what the message means and why it is occuring?

Comment: I'll try this again. A quick search points to two bugs in Brackets (#50 & #55): https://github.com/brackets-userland/brackets-eslint/issues/50

Comment: You can access  copy of this code at http://thetesting.site/js/setcurrentESLintExample.js

If you have Brackets installed, load that file and see what errors, if any, you get.

Comment: By the way, JSLint was telling me that the removeNode function was used before it was defined, I moved it to the top of the file, just below the comments to get rid of that message. The only message I get know is ESLint terminated with error. [object Object]

Comment: I didn't see anything in those bugs (50 and 55) that would apply to me except all of the talks about ESLint configuration settings and I'm not sure how to set them - how and where to set them - nor do I know their meanings. I'd have to hack at it until I accidentally got it right. On #55 - it was closed because someone could not replicate the problem and the OP never came back - or came back after it was closed. Brackets is getting a huge thumbs down from me. I'm going to uninstall it if I don't find a fix by the first of next week. ...

Comment: Brackets is getting a huge thumbs down from me. I'm going to uninstall it if I don't find a fix by the first of next week. I find Brackets very not intuitive and rather hard to use and with no support - well, I don't know why the bother to actual upgrade it.  Thanks for your reply. OH -- look at the answer by hossein sedighian and my comment on it. Am I missing something or is it just that his answer is incorrect. Seems to not know about scope of variables and also I can't get let past JSLint or ESLint in Brackets - it doesn't seem to know what it is....

Comment: Maybe some level/release problem with the JSLint and ESLint used by Brackets??   Thanks for your initial reply.

Comment: Perhaps..should check out VS Code.

Comment: Randy, Yes, I've had it with Brackets. I'll try the other IDEs. I do have a free copy of MS Expression Web. It has a great editor and lots of other features but it has not debugging features - no problem, just test in the browser.

Comment: I have the ConText editor and I've integrated a JSLint into it that checks just about everything but is not so picky about missing spaces in something like i=9; or when something is in column 6 instead of 5, etc. It is at http://www.javascriptlint.com/index.htm ConText editor is at http://www.contexteditor.org/index.php. The editor provides syntax highlighting and such for CSS, HTML, JavaScript, PHP and I thing some others. I have Expression Web open JS files in ConText editor instead of the native editor. Expression Web is at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36179...

Comment: I'm checking out IDEs to just get an idea of what is available - I'll stick with Expression Web and ConText. Hey, again, thanks for you initial reply - did you notice that it appears the other person deleted his answer?

Comment: I installed Brackets just now and I am getting the same error. The funny part is that my JavaScript file is empty.